# Can any trainers with shiny Pokémon be reliably encountered in Black/White 2?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Are there any trainers in *Pokémon Black / White 2* who have Pokémon that are reliably encountered as shiny?

Comment: I fought a two trainer with shiny Hippowdon twice in whiteforest ....

Comment: An alternate colour Hippowdon might not be a shiny. Male/female Hippowdon are differently coloured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really...

The only trainers (in the main series) you do encounter with shiny Pokemon are in Trainer Tower from Fire Red and Leaf Green (Gen 3). In the Single Battle mode, the seventh Trainer has a shiny Meowth. In Double Battle mode, the first trainer pair will have a shiny Espeon. In the Knockout mode, the fourth trainer will have a shiny Seaking.

Several trainers in Pokemon [Battle e](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Battle_e) (also Gen 3) have Pokémon that are shiny.

In B2/W2, you can encounter a shiny wild level 60 Haxorus in the middle of the [Nature Preserve](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nature_Preserve#Pok.C3.A9mon).

In Pokemon Conquest (technically it's Gen 5), Nobunaga uses a shiny Rayquaza in your final battle against him.